# Add password to Excel file in Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel-6, maatwebsite-excel

I am new at Laravel Framework. I tried to add a password to the excel file so it will be open just with it, but the file opens without inserting a password.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeExport;

class UserExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents
{
    protected $year;
    protected $month;

    public function __construct($year,$month)
    {
        $this->year = $year;
        $this->month = $month;
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            BeforeExport::class  => function(BeforeExport $event) {
                $event->writer->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
                $event->writer->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);
                $event->writer->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword("123456");
            },

            AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                $event->sheet->setRightToLeft(true);
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

can't find the answer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly PhpSpreadsheet only supports protecting data changes, not reading. If you need something like that, you'd probably need to go the password-protected zip route. You can try someone within the PhpSpreadsheet community knows more.

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/3152

https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/discussions/3151

Answer (score 0):

Because phpspreadsheet does not implement this function, but you can export the file first and then use https://github.com/nick322/secure-spreadsheet package to protect sensitive XLSX files.

```
use Nick\SecureSpreadsheet\Encrypt;

$test = new Encrypt();
$test->input('Book1.xlsx')
    ->password('111')
    ->output('bb.xlsx');
```